# Encryption Key Management Software and Transparent Data Encryption MySQL

Tags: mysql, pci-dss, key-management

For PCI compliance, is there any recommended Encryption Key Management Software? Open source preferable, but commercial is ok too. Is there a tool or software that provides both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ezNCrypt](http://www.gazzang.com/products/overview.html) looks like it may be useful, it promises TDE for MySql

You could also consider using MS SQL 2008 to store the card data, then look into [Extensible Key Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895340.aspx). There are a few EKM providers out there, such as [Thales](http://iss.thalesgroup.com/en/Products/Hardware%20Security%20Modules.aspx).  Using a 3rd party EKM would be easy (probably zero development time), but very costly (think $50k). With an EKM module you can then use [Transparent Data Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645957.aspx)

If you only want key management, without the transparent data encryption, then [StrongKey](http://www.strongkey.org/) is probably your best price/performance option. You'd need to spend some development time to integrate with it.

If you want to take the time and develop your own solution, then I can offer some help in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583553/how-to-properly-do-private-key-management)

Good luck!

Comment: That's a good amount of excellent information. eznCrypt looks promising, but seems to be pricey. Can I use the Java Key store implementation instead? Also, is StrongKey used in production environments?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Java, so in short - not sure, on either count. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[MyDiamo](http://www.mydiamo.com) is freeware for non-profit personal use, and commercial for another use.

You can encrypt datas in MySQL.
MyDiamo has developed under [Engine-Level Encryption](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/engine-level-encryption).
It provides "transparent" installation and encryption.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to pretend to answer the main question, but I would have thought that if the encryption is transparent, then that likely wouldn't address the usual concerns re PCI compliance.  That is to say, the encryption of things like credit card data being highly opaque from the point of view of your application is the whole point of the exercise.